# Exec tSQLt.Faketable crashing our original table constraint and data

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, sql-server-2012, tsqlt

During debugging the tsqlt code, I have directly run the below statement without wrapping it as sp and my original table constraint got deleted and some data missing from the original table.

Exec tSQLt.FakeTable @TableName = N'DBO.Employee', @Identity=1;
Exec tSQLt.FakeTable @TableName = N'DBO.Salary', @Identity=1;

How do I prevent running faketable statement in tsqlt is impacting the original table?

Comment: To avoid such issues, always execute unit tests using the tSQLt framework (e.g. `tSQLt.Run`). Don't execute procs like `tSQLt.FakeTable` directly. Furthermore, I suggest one execute unit tests against a sandbox database rather than a shared environment to avoid disruption.

Comment: It's a good point, but sometimes you're on autopilot, select things that you don't want to run and hit F5 and ad-hoc fake your tables...  Maddening.

Comment: In my tSQLt stored procedures I always have a first line being to exit out if `@@trancount` is zero. This protects against someone running the stored proc out of the test runner. But won't protect against you yourself running adhoc lines from it

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to prevent executing `tSQLt.FakeTable` outside of the framework. There are also good reasons to not prevent that, so I do not think that adding that functionality is the right approach.

However, if you’re using the newest version of tSQLt, you can use `tSQLt.UndoTestDoubles` to get the original object(s) back.

Comment: Maybe fake table should exit if not running in a transaction?

Comment: tSQLt has the ability to run test without transactions, so this is not an option, @MartinSmith.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, been there...  You can't prevent it, short of contributing to the project and putting a pull request in to add the functionality.

FakeTable creates a backup of your original table so you should be able to get the original table back.  These backup table names start with `tSQLt.tempobject` and end in an identifier.  You can delete the new "fake" table (which now has the name of your original table) and rename the tempobject table if/when you find it.

Something I've done in the past is to query for a column that I know is in the table to find the name of the tSQLt table:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.name = 'SomeCol';
```